# references in xamarin forms XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How would you make a reference in XAML vs code behind? It seems like ***mrkup:Class="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag"*** in the following snip would work

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ns.proj"
         mrkup:Class="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag"
         >
        ...
```

allowing the following.

```
    <mrkup:hr/>
```

I still get the undeclared prefix error.

I have tried backing down the tree to System.Web.UI and made sure I was not using a reserved word like html:xx and it still fails. I must be overlooking something basic or seriously missing a XAML/Xamarin.Forms premise.

---

**Update Edit:**

Based on Jason and Diego's input:
Intellisense kicked in after typing **using xmlns:mrkup="using:** resulting in

```
xmlns:mrkup="clr-namespace:System.Web;assembly=netstandard"
```

Which is a great start

```
 <mrkup:UI.HtmlTextWriterTag hr=""/>
```

Fails with *mrkup:UI.HtmlTextWriterTag.hr not found in xmlns clr-Namespace:System.Web;assembly=netstandard*

Is it possible that .UI is not in System.Web in .NET Standard 2.0?

---

**Update to the Update:**

It appears that UI is **NOT** in System.Web in .NET Standard 2.0. This is from the System.Web.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\NETStandard.Library\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\ref

[image: UI is **NOT** in System.Web in .NET Standard 2.0]

Comment: to use a new namespace, you have to declare it with "xmlns"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have to declare the `mrkup` prefix before use it.

Just like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ns.proj"
             xmlns:mrkup="clr-namespace:System.Web.UI;assembly:dllName">
...
    <mrkup:HtmlTextWriterTag hr="Property Value"/>
...
</ContentPage>
```

I'm not sure where the namespace ends, so in the snippet above I'm supposing the namespace is `System.Web.UI` and the class `HtmlTextWriterTag` and then you have a property `hr` on it. If the referred namespace is outside the actual project, you have to notice that `assembly` part of the declaration, but you can ignore it when referring to the class of the same assembly.

You can take a look at the [official docs from Microsoft about Declaring Namespaces for Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#declaring-namespaces-for-types) to get a more detailed information.

Comment: Intellisense kicked in after typing using xmlns:mrkup="using: resulting in xmlns:mrkup="clr-namespace:System.Web;assembly=netstandard" now to figure out how to dig into the UI and HtmlTextWriterTag.

Comment: Although there is no answer to System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag specifically. I feel that this is the answer to the basic question of adding references to Xamarin.Forms XAML. Marking it as such.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I don't believe you can reference `System.Web` on a `Xamarin.Forms` project... =/ You can search (or open if it didn't exist) to figure out if `UI is not in System.Web in .NET Standard 2.0`

Comment: I updated the post to show the ILSpy of System.Web in *.NET Standard 2.0* You could reference it but there are no UI elements to 'show' on the page.